# Changing dictionary type into list type by wrapping

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'Hello': 10, 'Tutorial': 20, 'python': 30}
```

I want to have it like this:

```
[{'Hello': 10, 'Tutorial': 20, 'python': 30}]
```

I tried but the output is not like the above.

Comment: If `d` is the dict then `[d]` is the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I tried but the output is not like the above." What does this mean? Exactly what did you try? What did you get as a result, and how is that different? "I want to have it like this:" - why? What problem do you hope to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
myDict = {"Hello": 10, "Tutorial": 20, "python": 30}
myDict = [myDict]
```

But if you can, it may just be easier to do:

```
myDict = [{"Hello": 10, "Tutorial": 20, "python": 30}]
```

if your situation means you can do that.

Comment: It works for me!
But doing directly `[{'Hello': 10, 'Tutorial': 20, 'python': 30}]` works for me too.

Comment: Good point, @Scarlet. But I'm not sure if that's what Nazmus-Sakub-Sumon intends.